# Windows 10 install from USB stuck on blank blue screen

Tags: windows-10, bios, bsod, windows-installation, bootable-media

I was having `winload.efi` error `0xc0000225`, so I tried to install Windows 10 (again) to my computer but during the boot, it is stuck like [this video](https://i.imgur.com/M6LSjOA.mp4), where it does not show anything, just the Windows logo and a blank blue screen. I can move my mouse and with Shift + F10 access the **CMD** but as you've guessed it doesn't work properly.

My BIOS options are:

- Boot again into UEFI and toggle the options below if present

  1. Disabled: Secure Boot
  2. Enabled:  Legacy Boot
  3. Enabled:  CSM Mode
  4. Disabled: all hard drive boots apart from USB

I have been trying to solve this issue for the last 5 days, and even if my disks are broken, shouldn't I be able to see a setup from Windows? This is my third USB *(some forums suggested to change the flash drive)* and I am trying every socket my laptop has, but I still just see this blank blue screen.

- I used Rufus to create media, but it didn't work, so I created one from via the Windows Media Creation Tool and it has the exact same result: 
   [image: Screenshot]

Comment: BIOS/UEFI are **not** the same things - you have UEFI. The entire setup is incorrect - in UEFI firmware settings,: **Secure Boot:** _ENABLED_ | **CSM [Legacy] Mode:** _DISABLED_ Save the settings and reboot to the USB. _[CSM Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI#CSM_booting) should never be enabled, as it's **sole purpose** was to allow EFI boot on distros that didn't yet support EFI boot circa <2017 (Windows has supported EFI boot since Win7)._ CSM Mode emulates BIOS' 16bit architecture within a 32bit environment within UEFI, which is 64bit, and doing so results in massive performance loss

Comment: @JW0914 thanks a lot for your comment but still it froze on blue screen. Did you check the video link? https://i.imgur.com/M6LSjOA.mp4 It tries to open windows but then its just blue.

Comment: UEFI requires GPT, not MBR. Note also the above comment.

Comment: Was this question deleted and resubmitted? I could have sworn I explained the reason enabling CSM and Legacy Mode is virtually the exact same thing in the last 24 hours.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, in the end it was my SSD (where windows was installed).0 It got corrupted data and whenever I tried to boot with windows usbs (3 in total with 3 different methods) it got stuck. And the reason for that was bootable win usb instances are always checking if there is a windows installed. Because my SSD was corrupted, it got stuck without showing anything. All that for that repair button.

**If you want to save your datas, Ubuntu bootable usb allows you to try ubuntu without installing it to your drivers. So basically, you run Ubuntu from USB.**

**If you have problem opening your disk from Ubuntu even if you see them:**

Open terminal and write

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

to list disks, /dev/sda1, /dev/sdb2, etc.

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda1
```

Will allow you to open the disk from file manager. If not, try restarting.

**If even with reaching the disk, you can't seem to be finding your files:**

I was mainly looking for my Baldur's Gate 3 saves (77 hours I have put in for that character ) But they were not in the folder. So for that you can search from terminal with

```
find /media/mydisk1 -type f -iname "*.lsv*"
```

lsv is the extension for BG3 save files. You can write anything you remember from the files you are searching `*` characters allows to find similar texts.After searching, found files would be stored in a folder, like `found.000` which will be in that USB you booted Ubuntu from. Now you can copy those files even though they are not visible in file explorer/manager. And they work.

Comment: @JW0914 I also tried USB, stopped at the blank blue screen and chkdsk also did not work with unspecified error occurred.  Problem was with Windows data being corrupted, and all external windows USBs (including PE, Windows to Go etc.) tried to reach it which caused the issue of the blank blue screen. Other obvious option is to take the SSD out and format it but I was using a laptop so didnt want to open it. Trust me I wasted 6 days on forums including microsoft. I dont understand your issue with the question/answer.

Comment: @JW0914 you did not even read the question, I was aware of Shift F10, setup GUI cant be seen as you can check from the imgur video...

Comment: I did read your question and fully watched the video. Your question stated "_I tried to install Windows 10 (again) to my computer but during the boot, it is stuck like this video,_" That implies it occurred after trying to install Windows, not after booting the install USB [WinPE], and it would be really odd for that behavior to occur when only booting from the Install USB when Ubuntu was able to be booted from a USB, as a corrupted filesystem wouldn't stop WinPE from booting - possibly could prevent `winpeshl` from starting, but if able to open a terminal, everything can be fixed from WinPE.

Comment: Precise language matters because Windows is installed in [seven phases](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/how-configuration-passes-work) _(incl. `generalize`)_: Install USB is booted → Setup GUI is traversed → Install begins → Setup copies files for `windowsPE` → Setup boots to WinPE _(where issue is implied)_: `offlineServicing` begins, then `specialize` → Setup boots to the partition the `install.esd`/`install.wim` image was applied to: `auditSystem` and `auditUser` begins _(if configured)_, finally `oobeSystem` starts → User gains access to the Desktop